# Longer Type descriptions in errors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How do I get longer typescript type descriptions in the error messages?

Right now I get error messages like:

`TS2345: Argument of type '(action: TAction<TPayloadPanelIdTitle>, undoHandler: "utx-handler-standard" | "utx-handler-crop" ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallEffectNamedFn<{ [x: string]: Func1<any>; }, string>'.
  Type '(action: TAction<TPayloadPanelIdTitle>, undoHandler: "utx-handler-standard" | "utx-handler-crop" ...' is not assignable to type '[{ [x: string]: Func1<any>; }, string]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type '(action: TAction<TPayloadPanelIdTitle>, undoHandler: "utx-handler-standard" | "utx-handler-crop" ...'.`

and the ellipses gulp away a lot of information. Frustrating!

**TypeScript Version:**  2.4.1